# Custom Cell Swipe with MGSwipeTableCell - Buttons not shown/empty white

Tags: swift, uitableview, github

I'm trying to implement buttons when cells are swiped to the left, according to the guide on [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell). They are swipeable now, However, the buttons are not shown, it's just a white space where the buttons are supposed to be.

Is that some kind of layer issue, or background problem?

What I have:

```
dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in

 let customCell = cell as! CustomCellTableViewCell
 customCell.rightButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor())
                ,MGSwipeButton(title: "More",backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGrayColor())]
            customCell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D
  ... }
```

And `CustomCellTableViewCell` is obviously a subclass of `MGSwipeTableCell`.

A screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

--- UPDATE:

So for simple testing I also added swipe to the right, with buttons on the left. They actually do show. On the right still nothing shows:
[image]